# How to check if a channel is joined?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I got channel by `client.get_entity(id)` using id stored locally and I need to check if I am still joined or not. I suspect it might be `not Channel.left` but I haven't found any docs about the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about `not channel.left` is correct. The docs about the field can be found here: https://core.telegram.org/constructor/channel.